# Eclipse: path variables expand to relative instead of absolut path

Tags: eclipse, git, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I want to build eclipse projects without eclipse. I want to put several dependent projects into one git repo.

I have a library project `l` and an executable project `p`.

I specify an include in `p` (under G++ Compiler -> Includes) as `"${workspace_loc:/l/include}`. The build goes well.

However the autogenerated `subdir.mk` has `-I"/home/user/workspace/l/include"`, i.e. the absolut path.

This makes it impossible to check out the git and build `p` without opening the project in eclipse first (which would update the relative paths).

Answer (score 0):

Use relative path in Includes Direcories rather than variables. E.g. something like this ../../l/include.